# Looking for a Sci Fi book with mercenaries defending a rich family

Tags: story-identification

What I can remember of the plot is that a family have immense wealth after building domes ( inventing a special material ), assassins want to kill them but they are protected by loyal mercenaries

Comment: 5 or 6 years ago I read the blurb on Amazon when it came up as a recommendation based on a book I was looking at.

Comment: Just the amazon recommendation

Comment: Yeah I thought that.  I should have brought it at the time !! Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I cannot remember what it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it is "Do Unto Others" (Freehold: Ripple Creek #2), written by Michael Z. Williamson.

The Prescot family develop domed playgrounds. And later need bodyguards to protect the father and daughter.

I have not read the book, but from the description it seems like what you are looking for.

[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7171612-do-unto-others)
[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00APAD7WI)

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you that is the book.

Comment: Hi Amarillo, Thanks... still getting familiar with the format